# What is the ideal way to append strings in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I need to create a string from a array of map in groovy.

Required string = `^(123|456|789)`

At present I am doing something like below, will this cause performance issue in production box or should I use StringBuffer java class?

```
def getProjectList(def caseResult) {
    def projectList = ""
    caseResult.each { projno ->
        if (projectList.length() == 0) {
            projectList = "^(${projno.project_no}|"
        } else {
            if (projectList.indexOf(projno.project_no) == -1)
                projectList+="${projno.project_no}|"
        }
    }
    projectList = projectList.substring(0, projectList.length() - 1)
    projectList += ')'
    return projectList
}
```

Comment: `will this cause performance issue` well, define _performance issue_ first.

Comment: What does you input _"array of map"_ look like?

Comment: @EelLee: OOM Exceptions

Comment: @tim_yates: groovy sql result set `[[project_no:0-1006, case_no:0178786], [project_no:1-2243239, case_no:018016], [project_no:1-2282337, case_no:020596], [project_no:1-232392, case_no:02040432]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for ease of reading...

```
def getProjectList(def caseResult) {
    "^(${caseResult.project_no.join('|')})"
}
```

Actually, you just want the unique ones don't you?

```
def getProjectList(def caseResult) {
    "^(${caseResult.project_no.unique().join('|')})"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a string from a array of map in groovy.

It would be extremely useful to define parameter type then. 
The return type too.

> will this cause performance issue in production box

Well, define *performance issue* first. Have you measured anything to think your code has any *performance issues*? If not, it looks like a typical "*premature optimization*"

> should I use StringBuffer java class

If you worry about performance, then you should rather use StringBuilder, as StringBuffer is thread-safe, taking a little performance hit.

If your code suffers from anything, it's rather readability than performance.
And I recommend you this StackExchange site, dedicated to such questions - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - give it a try!